# Posting values selected in drop-downs to controller

Tags: ajax, grails, gsp

I have a GSP with a dropdown as follows:

```
<select  onchange="display()" id="mv" class="wrapper-dropdown">
   <option value ="AFFILIATES">AFFILIATES</option>
   <option value ="CSE">CSE</option>
   <option value ="DISPLAYADS">DISPLAYADS</option>
   <option value ="EMAIL">EMAIL</option>
   <option value ="MOBILEWEB">MOBILEWEB</option>
   <option value ="ORGANIC">ORGANIC</option>
   <option value ="OTHERS">OTHERS</option>
   <option value ="SEM">SEM</option>
   <option value ="SEO">SEO</option>
</select>
```

I want to pass the following value to controller :

```
var m2 = document.getElementById('mv');
```

Following is a snippet from my controller:

```
def rows = sql.rows("select * from table xyz where mv = 'SELECTED'")
```

What should 'SELECTED' be replaced with and how can we pass m2 from GSP to controller such that it replaces 'SELECTED' with 'm2' passed from GSP?
Do we need remoteFunction here? How do we use it? I tried a few things but I am not getting the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

In your .gsp you can call the following:

```
    function passMvToController(e){
        var mvSelectedValue = $("#mv option:selected").text();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'${request.contextPath}/myController/myAction/?mv='+mvSelectedValue,
            success:function(data,textStatus){},
            error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){}
        });
    }
```

Then in your controller/action, you can use the value as such:

```
def myAction = {
    ...
    def rows = sql.rows("select * from table xyz where mv = '${params.mv}'")
    ...
}
```

Note that remoteFunction has been deprecated and will be removed from future versions of Grails - you will need to handle Ajax calls yourself if you plan on upgrading in the future.

Comment: I am getting an empty output. i think the value is not getting passed

Comment: Is the action in your controller even firing from this call? Edit: Try this, I updated the selector to get the value from the select - pretty sure this was the problem (Can't easily test this at the moment)

Comment: Hmm, I just set up a local test and it seems to be working fine. So the params.mv value is null, but your controller is firing? Try adding the line `log.debug "params == ${params}"` inside of your action that is being called - does this output anything?